# Guava Issue with deploying spring boot app in websphere

Tags: maven, spring-boot, websphere, guava, springfox

I have spring boot app which is working fine when I run as java application.

Now I followed steps from below url and tried deploying into websphere:
[How to deploy Spring Boot application in IBM Liberty and WAS 8.5](http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/java/spring-boot/deploy-spring-boot-application-ibm-liberty-8-5/)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/google/common/collect/Lists.reverse(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List; (loaded from file:/C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Downloads/spring-tool-suite-3.8.3.RELEASE-e4.6.2-win32-x86_64/sts-bundle/WLP/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/wps-source-document-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-collections-1.0.jar by com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader@9391165) called from class springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer (loaded from file:/C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Downloads/spring-tool-suite-3.8.3.RELEASE-e4.6.2-win32-x86_64/sts-bundle/WLP/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/wps-source-document-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar by com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader@9391165).
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2523) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1054) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6565) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:468) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:463) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1051) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.access$000(WebContainer.java:104) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$2.run(WebContainer.java:870) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.16.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522) [na:1.8.0]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277) [na:1.8.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153) [na:1.8.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [na:1.8.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785) [na:1.8.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/google/common/collect/Lists.reverse(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List; (loaded from file:/C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Downloads/spring-tool-suite-3.8.3.RELEASE-e4.6.2-win32-x86_64/sts-bundle/WLP/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/wps-source-document-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-collections-1.0.jar by com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader@9391165) called from class springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer (loaded from file:/C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Downloads/spring-tool-suite-3.8.3.RELEASE-e4.6.2-win32-x86_64/sts-bundle/WLP/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/wps-source-document-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar by com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader@9391165).
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer.jackson2Converters(ObjectMapperConfigurer.java:76) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer.configureMessageConverters(ObjectMapperConfigurer.java:63) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ObjectMapperConfigurer.java:47) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
... 29 common frames omitted
```

I noticed that there are few folks having similar issues in this link: [Exception caused by Guava library?](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/441)

Below is my latest dependency hierarchy tree with guava dependencies:[image]

I tried below solutions:

```
1) Updating springfox to various versions and see if it helps
2) Adding Guava 19.0 as dependency.
```

Comment: @Dilip Krishnan : Can you please take a look

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your springfox and google-collections jars are incompatible.  A NoSuchMethodError means that one class is calling a method that simply doesn't exist on the target class.  Per the exception message, this class:

springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer

is calling this method:

com.google.common.collect.Lists.reverse

which does not exist with that signature in the version of the class that has been loaded.

The exception shows which jars these classes came from (both are in your WAR's WEB-INF/lib):

ObjectMapperConfigurer from springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar

Lists from google-collections-1.0.jar

Given that you have guava in your app, I think the solution would just be to take out the old google-collections jar.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by taking out the old google-collections jar. In depenency hierarchy screenshot I shared I see that 19.0 is the version I am forcing all libraries to use.

Comment: I don't know your build environment (or maven in general, for that matter), but it's obviously getting into your application somehow.  Check your build environment for references to that jar name, because something's getting it in there.